# applying jquery code inside a foreachloop

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```html
@foreach($fiche as $f)
<tr id="trTab">
    <td>{{ $f->Date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $f->activite1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $f->heuresEffectu }}</td>
    <td>{{ $f->Poids }}</td>
    <td>{{ $f->ecart }}</td>

    <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
        <td>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$f->id}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="valider" onclick="">V</button>
        </td>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="refuser">R</button>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

and i have this jquery code which disables a button when i click on it :

```html
<script>
    $("#valider").click(function() {
        if ($('#refuser').prop("disabled")) {
            $('#refuser').attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#refuser').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        $("#form1").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

the jquery code is working fine but the problem is whenever i click on one of the buttons it only works for the first row , how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP CODE:

```
@foreach($fiche as $f)
<tr id="trTab">        
            <td>{{ $f->Date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->activite1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->heuresEffectu }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->Poids }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->ecart }}</td>
           
            <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
            <td>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$f->id}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" class="valider" data-id="{{$f->id}}" onclick="">V</button>
            </td></form>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="refuser_{{$f->id}}" data-id="{{$f->id}}">R</button>
            </td>
            </form>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

1. Your code won't work as multiple Same IDs are there and that is the first thumbrule.
2. If you have multiple elements than try to use class instead of id.
   I have added class="valider" instead of id.
3. To differenciate which class is clicked you can see I have added data attribute data-id="" will give extra attribute which can help you to retrieve which class id clicked.

Your final jquery code can be like this:

```
<script>
    $(".valider").click(function() {
        //get current id which was clicked
        var current_id = $(this).data("id");
        if ($('#refuser_'+current_id).prop("disabled")) {
            $('#refuser_'+current_id).attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#refuser_'+current_id).attr("disabled", true);
        }
        $("#form1").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're re-using the same `id` value multiple times on the page.  So when you query the DOM for an element by `id`:

```
$("#valider")
```

Which one is it going to refer to?  I suspect the behavior is undefined because the markup is invalid, but generally browsers will find the *first* element with that `id` and then simply stop looking because there *shouldn't be* more elements with the same `id`.

**First**, move all of your `id` values within that loop into `class` values.  These *can* be re-used and applied to multiple elements on the page.  For example, this:

```
<tr id="trTab">
```

Becomes this:

```
<tr class="trTab">
```

Be sure to do this with *all* of the `id` values within that loop.

**Second**, update your click handler to select by `class` instead of `id`.  So this:

```
$("#valider").click(function() {
  //...
});
```

Becomes this:

```
$(".valider").click(function() {
  //...
});
```

Note that this will attach a *separate* click handler to every matched `".valider"` element.  If there are potentially many of them, you can improve performance by using a single click handler at a higher level, taking advantage of event propagation.  In that case you'd use this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".valider", function() {
  //...
});
```

This would instead place *one* click handler at the `document` level, catching every click anywhere in the document, but only invoke the handler function if the originating element matches the `".valider"` selector.

**Third**, within your click handler you need to determine which elements you want to reference.  For example, you can't just do this:

```
$(".form1").toggle();
```

Because it will target *every* matching `".form1"` element.  You can use DOM traversal in jQuery to navigate to the target elements.  Starting from `this` (which is the element that was clicked) you can traverse *up* to a common parent element with `.closest()` and then traverse *down* to your target element(s) with `.find()`.  So this:

```
$(".form1").toggle();
```

Becomes this:

```
$(this).closest(".trTab").find(".form1").toggle();
```

Do this for each of your jQuery selectors which formerly relied on `id` values.

Overall, the goal here is to not always rely on `id` values for selecting elements.  You can select an element in a variety of ways, and from within the event handler you can select or find your other relevant elements in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use class attributes instead of id's.

Class attributes can be referenced into multiple elements and you can use the $(this) to make sure you get the exact clicked attribute.

```
<script>
 $(".valider").click(function () {}
</script>
```